# Error in query passing in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing windows phone 8 application.

I need to pass a value from one page to another page.

I set up Splash.xaml as start-up page from this page i need to pass a value to main.xaml page.

In Splash.xaml Page

```
 String add = "test";
  this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/MainPage.xaml?Businessname={0}", add), UriKind.Relative));
```

In main.xaml page

```
  static string businessnamereturn;

  void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        businessnamereturn = NavigationContext.QueryString["Businessname"];
        Locationname.Text = businessnamereturn;

    }
```

businessnamereturn = NavigationContext.QueryString["Businessname"]; In this line follwing error occur

**An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TravelAmericaVistorGuid.DLL but was not handled in user code**

How to solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the value you can also define a Global variable in App.xaml

```
public string add { set; get; }
```

In your Splash page you can assign the value

```
 ((App)(App.Current)).add = "test";
```

In Mainpage.xaml

```
static string businessnamereturn;
businessnamereturn=((App)(App.Current)).add;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try on `OnNavigatedTo` method

```
String add = "test";
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?myKey=" + add, UriKind.Relative));
```

Your on navigated to method

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("myKey"))
    {
         businessnamereturn = NavigationContext.QueryString["myKey"];
         Locationname.Text = businessnamereturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing your key...!

Answer (score 0):

In Splash.xaml Page

```
  String add = "test";
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?Businessname=" + add +  "",UriKind.Relative));
```

In main.xaml page

```
static string businessnamereturn;

 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry(); 
            businessnamereturn = NavigationContext.QueryString["Businessname"];
            Locationname.Text = businessnamereturn;
        }
```

Comment: To pass the value you can also define a Global variable in App.xaml      public string add { set; get; }